# unable to load nested object data in mongoose database properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

The issue I am facing is that even though I am able to load the data in the database but the desired result is different from what is being returned.

The issue is that whenever I am running for loop the qn variable is inserted twice but need it only once.

Please if someone can help me resolve this issue.

userProject.js

```
router.post('/notification/check/upload/survey' , async (req,res) => {
 
  //const taginsert = [];
  const mcq = [];
  //const newData = {};
  //const o = {};

  console.log(req.body);

  for(var i=0; i<=req.body.questions.length-1;i++) {
    //  newData = {
    //   qn: req.body.questions[i].qn
    // }
    for(var j=0; j<=req.body.questions[i].options.length-1;j++){
       const o = 
        {
         qn: req.body.questions[i].qn,
        //{
            options: [{
            option: req.body.questions[i].options[j].option,
            totalValues: req.body.questions[i].options[j].totalValues
          }]
        }
       
     // newData.options = o;  
    //  newData.push(o);

      mcq.push(o); 
    }
   
  }
  

//mcq = newData;

const check = new userCampaignSurvey({
  userId: req.body.userId,
  status: 'Pending',
  notification_type:req.body.notification_type,
  questions: mcq
})

 check.save((err,p) => {
  if(err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
  res.status(201).send(p);
 })
})
```

model.js

```
 userId: 
    {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    notification_id: 
    {
        type: Number,
    },
    notification_type: 
    {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
       
    },
    status: 
    {       
         type: String,
         required: true
    },

    questions: [
        {
            qn: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        options: [
            { 
                option: {
                    type: String
                },
                totalViews: {
                    type:Number
                }

             } 
    ]    
    },
    ],
    created_at:  {       
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: Date.now(),
},
   
});
```

result received

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "notification_type": 1,
    "status": "Pending",
    "questions": [
        {
            "qn": "Which brand do you like better for buying shoes?",
            "options": [
                {
                    "option": "Adidas",
                    "_id": "639064c9ec215f2cd1b2b15d"
                }
            ],
            "_id": "639064c9ec215f2cd1b2b15c"
        },
        {
            "qn": "Which brand do you like better for buying shoes?",
            "options": [
                {
                    "option": "Reebok",
                    "_id": "639064c9ec215f2cd1b2b15f"
                }
            ],
            "_id": "639064c9ec215f2cd1b2b15e"
        }
    ],
    "created_at": "2022-12-07T10:02:48.442Z",
    "_id": "639064c9ec215f2cd1b2b15b",
    "__v": 0
}
```

expected result

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "status": "Pending",
    "notification_type": 1,
    "questions": [
        {
            "qn": "Which brand do you like better for buying shoes?",
            "options": [
                {
                    "option": "Adidas",
                    "totalViews": 20
                },
                {
                    "option": "Reebok",
                    "totalViews": 10
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The result is as per the schema, try moving the options into the questions array in the model.

Comment: No the issue is that qn is getting inserted on every loop..whereas If u check the structure qn should be only one then the options